# Simplifying polygon edge while preserving minimum area and width

Tags: buffer, simplify, generalization, outline

I am working with river buffer areas. The area that you see in the first picture is a 100-meter buffer of a polyline (a polyline isn't visible but it is there).
[image]

I want to simplify the edge in a way, where I connect the maximum points (red dots) on each "bump" as shown in the second photo while still preserving the minimum distance (width) of 100 meters from the polyline. Basically, I want to remove all the "dents" and make the edge more smooth.
[image]

The expected result (What I would like to achieve) is in the third photo. The edge should be the same or similar to the red line, which I have manually draw on it.
[image]

Is there a way to do this automatically (with a tool)? Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Which software is that?

Comment: I can't comment seems like, so I will post here. I forgot to mention, I am using ArcMap 10.5 (I know there are newer versions of it, but we still use this one :/ )
But I can also use QGIS if necessary

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable about how this site works (start with the [tour]: all relevant information should be included in the body of the initial question, not in a commet. Add the information about the software to the body of the question by editing it. By the way: Questions that do not focus on one specific software risk to be closed, so either focus on one software or make it clear that the question is not software-specific. Also have a look to the answer posted. If it does not solve your problem, make clear what is missing.

Comment: Babel thanks for your feedback. I am working on this solution, till now I thik its going to be OK

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possibilities: convex and concave hull. This is not software specific, both kind of hulls can be created with different software packages. The description here is based on QGIS 3.20:

1. Convex hull: `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Minimum bounding geometry`, then select `Convex hull` (solid red line on the screenshot).
2. Concave hull: `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Concave hull (k-nearest neighbor)`. Set the value for `Number of neighboring points to consider (a lower number is more concave, a higher number is smoother)`: The smaller the value, the nearer to the original buffer it is. The larger it is, the closer it is to the concave hull. The red dotted line is created with a value of `30`.

[image]